# Get value multiple button created by checked checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get value from button.
This button appear when checkbox checked.

if only one button, it's ok, but when there is so many button it will fetch last button data-attr which is not good

```js
$('#other-products').on('change', function() {
    var selectedProducts = [];
    var listProductsCtrl = $('.list-products');
    listProductsCtrl.html('');
    $('#other-products input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
      selectedProducts.push($(this).attr('name'));
      var showtimesAsString = '<button class="number" data-label="'+$(this).attr('name')+'">'+selectedProducts.join('</button> <button class="test">')+'</button>';
      listProductsCtrl.html(showtimesAsString);
      
    });
    $('.number').click(function(){
      
       alert($(this).attr('data-label'));
      
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="other-products">
  <input type="checkbox" name="First" value="1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="Second" value="2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="Third" value="3">
</div>
<span class="list-products"></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for 2nd and 3rd you are appending class `test` not number, and that does not having `data-label` attribute

SO here i just display `text()` here.

```js
$('#other-products').on('change', function() {
    var selectedProducts = [];
    var listProductsCtrl = $('.list-products');
    listProductsCtrl.html('');
    $('#other-products input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
      selectedProducts.push($(this).attr('name'));
      var showtimesAsString = '<button class="number" data-label="'+$(this).attr('name')+'">'+selectedProducts.join('</button> <button class="test">')+'</button>';
      listProductsCtrl.html(showtimesAsString);
      
    });
    $('.number, .test').click(function(){
      
       alert($(this).text());
      
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="other-products">
  <input type="checkbox" name="First" value="1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="Second" value="2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="Third" value="3">
</div>
<span class="list-products"></span>
```

Comment: Oh I see, Thanks. I know also my data-label it's change so I will fetch from text. but it's there any way to make data-label change?

Comment: append label when you add button.